# Magento 2: Update the validation message on first name,last name,company, street address, city, state

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to update the validation message like by default we get **This is required field** but i want to update like for the firstname i want to fire the **First name is required** how can i do that?

Comment: In your checkout form or register form?

Comment: for the both register and checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go-to that input field and add a custom attribute "data-msg-required"

data-msg-(validator name), For Ex:

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate='{"required":true}' data-msg-required="Please select size."/>
```

Comment: For the firstname how can i do because there is widget call

Comment: For more info visit this link: that help you.
Link - http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento2-custom-form-validation/